# Create unique index over JSONB array in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing, constraints, jsonb

I have a JSONB like:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "labels": ["ABC", "CBA", "DEF"],
  "created_time": ...
}
```

I want add unique constraint for lables (all this labels should be uniq).
One option is a function in Postgres, but I don't like it.

Do you have any other ideas?